# Silent login - Angular web app with Apache Airlfow iframe

Tags: angular, airflow, keycloak

Is there a way to make silent login with Apache Airflow within an iframe?
I've got an Angular app and Apache Airflow webserver configured to login with the same Keycloak using code flow (under the same realm and client).

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up Apache Airflow to use OIDC authentication with Keycloak.
2. Set up your Angular app to use OIDC Implicit Flow or OIDC Authorization Code Flow with PKCE to authenticate with Keycloak.
3. Within your Angular app, create an iframe that points to the Apache Airflow webserver's login page.
4. When creating the iframe, add the Keycloak access token as a URL parameter to the login page URL.
5. Within Apache Airflow, use a custom authentication backend to read the access token from the URL parameter and authenticate the user.